# KQL - Query Usage Time who only shows me the Results between 08:00 and 17:00 Time

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

i have a Question about a Query in KQL.
I would like to use a Time at the KQL Query who only shows me the Results between 08:00 and 17:00 Time.

How can i build these at the KQL Query?
Im only find the DateTime Variable but i need only the Time?

Thanks a lot.

Regards,
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is the example to show logs between specific time:

```
let start=datetime("10/26/2022 1:04:27.627 AM");
let end=datetime("10/26/2022 1:22:53.745 AM");
traces
| where timestamp > start and timestamp < end
```

[image]

If you only want timestamp then:

```
let start=datetime("10/26/2022 1:04:27.627 AM");
let end=datetime("10/26/2022 1:22:53.745 AM");
traces
| where  timestamp > start and timestamp < end 
| project timestamp
```

[image]

You can give your date and time in end and start in query.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp%1d will give us only the time part of the day (timespan).

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let t = materialize (range i from 1 to 20 step 1 | extend Timestamp = ago(7d * rand()));
// Solution starts here.
t
| where Timestamp%1d between (8h .. 17h)
| order by Timestamp%1d asc // Just for display
```

| i | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | 2022-10-19T**08:26:45**.2144968Z |
| 1 | 2022-10-23T**12:00:21**.8528635Z |
| 16 | 2022-10-19T**12:50:27**.4405648Z |
| 19 | 2022-10-19T**13:00:48**.9000836Z |
| 2 | 2022-10-24T**13:19:30**.956558Z |
| 8 | 2022-10-25T**13:51:25**.726857Z |
| 10 | 2022-10-22T**14:12:09**.8304847Z |
| 7 | 2022-10-25T**14:51:14**.3011525Z |
| 14 | 2022-10-20T**15:21:04**.5173436Z |
| 11 | 2022-10-20T**16:04:06**.412613Z |
| 12 | 2022-10-19T**16:48:54**.0581289Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WNMQrCQBRE%200DuMI2QWCTGRkHsrG30Al93TBaS3bD7JSoe3lUEsRxm3ry6xk5UEGUYe6KlYxC13lXYe8UoQeEv0I6Ivr9%20mjzrqVBsMYgyWOntgyiCuJawuAQ/oIF6LBeIyjGFJ3hTOoOjHRg1yRItrS9WBnMk0hRlWW7yrK5x%20HoSm%20wRHQOTU/PsiekdfiezxuBEnUiHYt2hqtCsuvK99MEw4HT/H0s8vwCaetUF8gAAAA==)

Comment: Hey, 

thanks for your Answer but it doesnt works.
When i use this 

availabilityResults
| where timestamp%1d between (08h..17h)

It shows me not only the Results between 08:00 and 17:00. It shows me many more days and other time ranges.

Comment: Sorry i must say, that i only would like to see the results from this day.

Comment: That's a completely different story. Please accept the answer for this question and post a new question for the modified version.